# how to use data annotation for numeric value in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I got attribute in sql server 2012 database of data type numeric (18,0), how I am going to model using data annotation in asp.net mvc-5 app.

this code giving me following error...

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The 'PassMark' property on 'MarkScheme' could not be set to a  'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'
```

Many Thanks

### SQL Image

[image]

### Model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Pass Mark")]
 [Display(Name = "Pass Mark")]
 public int PassMark { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [RegularExpression]. like yzi_20004 but your issue is that you set

```
  public int PassMark { get; set; }
```

and it should be

```
    public decimal PassMark { get; set; }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use following attribute for validation -

```
[Range(0, 999999999999999999)]
```

And your C# property should be -

**Updated EDIT**

```
public decimal PassMark { get; set; }
```

Comment: @toxic Can you share actual Range code you used? and what error you got?

Comment: @toxic, have you used - `[Range(0, 999999999999999999)]`

Comment: yes i did and i am getting following error... Additional information: The 'PassMark' property on 'MarkScheme' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'.

Answer (score 0):

I always using [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{0,18}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrMsg_ID")]